# клиент-сервер программа

Tags: c#, c++, linux, сервер

клиент-серверная программа. которая работает по IP.
программа (клиент) Ростелеком c ip 22.22.22 подключается к программе(сервер) Билайн ip 55.55.55.

для подключения используется прямое подключение по IP.

вопрос. если клиент(программа) Ростелеком подключился к серверу(программа) Билайн. Видит ли провайдер Билайн некое подключение к IP Ростелекома и на оборот?

p.s. программа клиент-серверную. наподобии UltraVNC или TightVNC.

Comment: Конечно видит, иначе как он сможет обеспечить передачу данных по этому соединению

Answer (score 0):

Ваше подключение можно увидеть во многих местах. В домовом коммутаторе его могут перехватить любые люди с молотком и гвоздодером. В серверах доступа провайдера его видят администраторы провайдера, также там сведения о подключениях передаются на биллинг. В коммутаторах ядра сети сети ваши соединения копируются на 2 железки: фильтр роскомнадзора и СОРМ.  На фильтре никто не смотрит, там в автоматическом режиме всё работает (доступ у администраторов провайдера), но можно добавить правила блокировки. На СОРМ доступ есть у кураторов ФСБ - там они могут записать всё что их интересует. Трафик дальше идёт  в магистральную сеть и на узлы обмена трафиком (IX - internet exchange). В этом месте что-то искать бесполезно - слишком много трафика. С IX соединение идет к другому оператору и там всё в обратном порядке.

Защитить содержимое от прослушки можно через программу stunnel для одиночных соединений или через ipsec - чтоб защитить направление вцелом.